# error in my login screen "can't find variable"

Tags: react-native, variables, use-state

I wanted to test a tutorial that I found here: https://aboutreact.com/react-native-login-and-signup/ I found it interesting to use it for my application.
I wanted to adapt the code to my API etc.
It seemed to me to have done everything correctly but I made mistakes, and I would have liked to have had your help to see them, understand them and correct them ...

Example with the Login file

import React, { useState } from 'react';

```
import {
  TextInput,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Keyboard,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
import Loader from '../../src/components/Loader';
import styles from '../../assets/styles';
import i18n from '../../src/i18n'

import {
  API_URL,
  API_SOCIETYID,
  API_SECRETKEY,
} from "../../src/common/Constants";



const Register = props => {
  let [userName, setUserName] = useState('');
  let [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState('');
  let [userAge, setUserAge] = useState('');
  let [userAddress, setUserAddress] = useState('');
  let [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  let [errortext, setErrortext] = useState('');
  let [isRegistrationSuccess, setIsRegistrationSuccess] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmitButton = () => {
    setErrortext('');
    if (!userName) {
      alert(i18n.t("register.action.errorName"));
      return;
    }
    if (!userEmail) {
      alert(i18n.t("register.action.errorMail"));
      return;
    }
    if (!userAge) {
      alert(i18n.t("register.action.errorAge"));
      return;
    }
    if (!userAddress) {
      alert(i18n.t("register.action.errorAdress"));
      return;
    }
    
    setLoading(true);
    var dataToSend = {
      user_name: userName,
      user_email: userEmail,
      user_age: userAge,
      user_address: userAddress,
    };
    var formBody = [];
    for (var key in dataToSend) {
      var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(key);
      var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(dataToSend[key]);
      formBody.push(encodedKey + '=' + encodedValue);
    }
    formBody = formBody.join('&');

    fetch(
          API_URL +
            "/users?society_id=" + API_SOCIETYID +
            "&access_token=" + "accessToken" +
            "&lang=fr",
          {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              Accept: "application/json",
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              Authorization: "Bearer " + API_SECRETKEY,
              "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
              Pragma: "no-cache",
              Expires: "0",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              userEmail: UserEmail,
              mobilephone: phone,
              password: pwd,
              imei: "0000000000",
              os: Platform.OS === "ios" ? "iOS" : "Android",
            }),
          }
        )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        //Hide Loader
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(responseJson);
        
        if (responseJson.status == 1) {
          setIsRegistrationSuccess(true);
          console.log('Registration Successful. Please Login to proceed');
        } else {
          setErrortext('Registration Unsuccessful');
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setLoading(false);
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
  if (isRegistrationSuccess) {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: '#307ecc',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}>
        
        <Text style={styles.successTextStyle}>{i18n.t("register.action.success")}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.buttonStyle}
          activeOpacity={0.5}
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Login')}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonTextStyle}>Login Now</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#F78400'}}>
      <Loader loading={loading} />
      <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Image
            source={require('../../assets/images/accounting.png')}
            style={{
              width: '50%',
              height: 100,
              resizeMode: 'contain',
              margin: 30,
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView enabled>
          <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.inputStyle}
              onChangeText={UserName => setUserName(UserName)}
              underlineColorAndroid="#FFFFFF"
              placeholder="Enter Name"
              placeholderTextColor="#F6F6F7"
              autoCapitalize="sentences"
              returnKeyType="next"
              onSubmitEditing={() =>
                _emailinput && _emailinput.focus()
              }
              blurOnSubmit={false}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.inputStyle}
              onChangeText={UserEmail => setUserEmail(UserEmail)}
              underlineColorAndroid="#F6F6F7"
              placeholder="Enter Email"
              placeholderTextColor="#F6F6F7"
              keyboardType="email-address"
              ref={ref => {
                _emailinput = ref;
              }}
              returnKeyType="next"
              onSubmitEditing={() => _ageinput && _ageinput.focus()}
              blurOnSubmit={false}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.inputStyle}
              onChangeText={UserAge => setUserAge(UserAge)}
              underlineColorAndroid="#F6F6F7"
              placeholder="Enter Age"
              placeholderTextColor="#F6F6F7"
              keyboardType="numeric"
              ref={ref => {
                _ageinput = ref;
              }}
              onSubmitEditing={() =>
                _addressinput && _addressinput.focus()
              }
              blurOnSubmit={false}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.inputStyle}
              onChangeText={UserAddress => setUserAddress(UserAddress)}
              underlineColorAndroid="#FFFFFF"
              placeholder="Enter Address"
              placeholderTextColor="#F6F6F7"
              autoCapitalize="sentences"
              ref={ref => {
                _addressinput = ref;
              }}
              returnKeyType="next"
              onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}
              blurOnSubmit={false}
            />
          </View>
          {errortext != '' ? (
            <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle}> {errortext} </Text>
          ) : null}
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.buttonStyle}
            activeOpacity={0.5}
            onPress={handleSubmitButton}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonTextStyle}>{i18n.t("register.action.register")}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};
export default Register;
```

it gives me

> "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: UserEmail"

Comment: So, a good first step is to read the error message. 1) Can't find variable `UserEmail`. 2) CTRL+F `UserEmail` 3) Replace with correct name (`userEmail`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm truly sorry I thought it was a problem of declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `UserEmail` to `userEmail`

```
body: JSON.stringify({
     userEmail: userEmail, // here
     ........
 }),
```

Comment: thank you so much, I'm so sorry, I thought I did wrong in the states.... sorry !